# Is there a way to read a txt file into a list without using List<String>?

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to read a .txt file into a list without using a `List<string>` type. I have created a separate class, called Club, that does all of the sorting. However, I am having difficulties actually reading in the .txt file.

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Clubs-2019";

public List<Club> ReadClubsTxtFile()
{
    List<Club> outcome = new List<Club>();
    string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    outcome.Add(text);
    return outcome;
}
```

The line `outcome.Add(text);` shows an error as I am trying to send the wrong type to the list.

This is a sample of the text file:

> Club Name Club Number Meeting Address Latitude    Longitude   Meeting Day Meeting Time    Meeting End Time
>   Alabaster-Pelham  4018    1000 1st St North Alabaster AL 35007    33.252414   -86.813044  Thursday    12:15 PM    1:15 PM
>   Albertville   4019    860 Country Club Road Albertville AL 35951  34.296807   -86.198587  Tuesday 12:00 PM    1:00 PM
>   Alexander City    29375   16 Broad St. Alexander City AL 35010    32.945387   -85.953948  Monday  12:00 PM    1:00 PM

The "Clubs" Class is shown below.

```
public Club(string name, ClubTypes type, long idNumber, RecurrableMeeting regularMeeting = null, RecurrableMeeting boardMeeting = null, List<IndividualMeeting> otherMeetings = null)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.regularMeeting = regularMeeting;
        this.boardMeeting = boardMeeting;

        this.otherMeetings = otherMeetings;
        if (this.otherMeetings == null)
            this.otherMeetings = new List<IndividualMeeting>();
    }
```

Comment: You need to have a way to convert a string into a `Club`. What is this way?

Comment: You need to create a club out of each string it seems. How are you going to parse the string in order to create an instance of club? What does this file look like?

Comment: Can you post the code for your club class and a sample of the text file.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, guess I did not read the question correctly.  Thought `outcome ` was a list of string.

Comment: Its fine ;) no problem.

Comment: @preciousbetine, It may still be it. Club class might have a Name property and he might simply be willing to create a list of them from a text file where each line has a club name.

Comment: Any time you ask about code that “shows an error” you need to tell us the error.

Comment: @cat, please post a sample of your text file. How the data is stored in the text file makes a huge difference of how you can/should convert it into a C# list.

Comment: @CetinBasoz. That might also not be it. The text file may contain lines where each line will need to be processed further before assigning the values from the output to the properties of the club class and then adding it to the list.

Comment: @preciousbetine, well it may be. His code telling the otherwise. End result wouldn't really change and that would need a simple line added to the code I gave below.

Comment: The very basic reason for the error is that the `.Add()` method can only add an object of the correct type, which in your case is a `Club`, and you are trying to add a `string[]`.

Answer (score 6):

> *"The line "outcome.Add(text); " shows an error as I am trying to send the wrong type to the list."*

The reason for this error is that you're trying to add a `string[]` to a list that contains `Club`. What we need is a method that will take a `string` and return a `Club`, and then we can call that method on each file line before adding to the list.

A common way to do this is to add a `Parse` method to the `Club` class that can create an instance of the class from a string.

A complete example could be provided if you shared some sample lines from the text file (typically these would map to properties of the class) and the definition of the `Club` class. However, here is a sample that you can hopefully apply to your specific situation.

First, example lines in a text file:

```
1,Ravens,10/10/2019,2
2,Lions,05/25/2019,5.7
3,Tigers,09/12/2018,6.2
4,Bears,11/05/2019,9.1
5,Wildcats,03/04/2017,4.8
```

And the definition of `Club`

```
public class Club
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime FoundedOn {get; set;}
    public double Score {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, the lines in the text file map to properties of the `Club` class. Now we just need to add a `static` method to the `Club` class that returns an instance of the class based on a line of text from the file.

The idea is that we split the line on the comma character, convert each part to the correct data type for the property, set the properties, and return the class. We need to validate things like:

- The line is not null
- The line contains the correct number of parts
- Each part is the correct datatype

In the case of a validation failure, we have some common choices:

- Throw an exception
- Return `null`
- Return a partially populated class

In the sample below I'm returning `null` to indicate bad data, mostly because it makes parsing the file easier.

Here's the class with the `Parse` method added:

```
public class Club
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime FoundedOn { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public static Club Parse(string input)
    {            
        // Try to split the string on the comma and
        // validate the result is not null and has 4 parts
        var parts = input?.Split(',');
        if (parts?.Length != 4) return null;

        // Strongly typed variables to hold parsed values
        int id;
        string name = parts[1].Trim();
        DateTime founded;
        double score;

        // Validate the parts of the string
        if (!int.TryParse(parts[0], out id)) return null;
        if (name.Length == 0) return null;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(parts[2], out founded)) return null;
        if (!double.TryParse(parts[3], out score)) return null;

        // Everything is ok, so return a Club instance with properties set
        return new Club {Id = id, Name = name, FoundedOn = founded, Score = score};
    }
}
```

Now that we have the parse method, we can create a `List<Club>` from the text file quite easily:

```
public static List<Club> ReadClubsTxtFile(string path)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(Club.Parse).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Great possible solution and explanation.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, how could you deduct that is not a wrong answer now ;)

Comment: Now this is an answer

Comment: @CetinBasoz, at a bare minimum, Rufus has admitted that he doesn't have a sample of 'Club' or of the text file in question, and he provided his own. Your answer has so many potential ways it might fail. You didn't explain or allow for any of them.  Rufus did.  And last of all, Rufus did one key thing that you didn't... he taught!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston LOL

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no way of parsing the data to begin with. I have added a sample of the txt file to my question, as well as the Club class.

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Clubs-2019";
public List<Club> ReadClubsTxtFile()
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(path)
               .Select( line => new Club {SomeProperty = line} )
               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: There is too much we don't know about the text file. Is it a csv? Is it a json blob? Is it xml? W/o that kind of info, giving an answer seems premature.

Comment: By the OP's own admission: `The line "outcome.Add(text); " shows an error as I am trying to send the wrong type to the list.` Something is wrong with his code, but we have no idea what, because we can't see the raw text he is trying to convert.